# System for 2 Raspberry Pis to wirelessly communicate about 100 meters apart

Tags: streaming-video, communication

I am looking for a system that could connect 2 Raspberry Pis and send video data as well as input for a program. Under $100 would be preferred, and no access to the internet is required. What are some solutions that would work well with Raspberry Pi?

Comment: There is nothing special about the Raspberry Pi in this regard.  You could look for a solution using any Linux boxes.

Comment: Is the wireless part absolutely necessary?
For about $100 you can buy a set of [entry level Fiber media converters][1] and as much fiber optic cable you need.  These media converters will cap at 100Mbps, but your Pi network interface won't do faster anyway.

Don't be afraid of fiber especially with those media converters.  It's plug & play, practically no config needed.

  [1]: http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-4792_MC112CS.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the software point of view, I suggest [UV4L](http://linux-projects.org). It does Audio and/or Video live streaming from Rpi to browser and works **out-of-the-box**. It can stream from `USB` webcams (with the `uv4l-uvc` driver) or from the Camera Module (`uv4l-raspicam` driver) or even IP cameras (`uv4l-mjpegstram` driver). Should you need it, audio is two-way optionally. It's also possible to overlay any data on the video frames being streamed, if that is ok for your application. USB webcams are a little more CPU consuming than the native Camera module.

Comment: why is it not an answer?

Comment: By my reading the question is about a hardware system capable of communicating wirelessly at 300' with a bandwidth capable of video, not about software streaming.   But I guess there are some ambiguities.

Comment: Seems to be what I need, I might be able to get something else for video, if so this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry PIs are not really suitable for sending video unless you are recording it with a Raspberry PI camera. http://archpi.dabase.com/#sending-and-receiving-pi-camera-video-over-the-network

As for wirelessly communicate... this will probably cost more like 200USD to get decent wireless gear up to the task. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=__xzHnK6IVs

Comment: I don't see why sending video from a USB (or whatever) source would be any different than sending it from a raspicam source.

Comment: USB is CPU intensive

Comment: Not particularly, and certainly not enough in this case to make it "unsuitable".   The camera is going to do most of the work, all the pi then has to do is stream the output -- exactly the same case as with the raspicam.